# Facing problem while deploying my site in firebase

Tags: firebase

While deploying my site in firebase they show me i have completed deploying but don't  show me anything in the page. Why this happen?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check are you using the correct fireplace project from run this command

```
firebase use
```

It will show you active project

```
Active Project: dev (...your project name...)
```

just in case you have multiple project.